# How to page up and down in the Ctrl + Alt + F3 virtual terminal window?

Tags: linux, terminal, tty

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Every now and then, I like to escape the noise of windows by pressing `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F3` where I login using to one of the ready to use terminal windows.

If I cat a file and the contents scroll past the screen height, how can I view what's gone off the top of the screen? Pressing Page Up does nothing. Page Down appears to echo a `~` character.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Shift` + `Page Up` or `Shift` + `Page Down`.

You should also be using `more`/`less` to read files, not `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the standard terminal utilities to manage the virtual console terminals.

- [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)
- [tmux](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux)
- possible [byobu](http://byobu.co/) (I don't have experience with this one and am not certain)

You could also use the standard terminal tools like `less` and `more`.